# Errors nginx: 'Welcome to nginx' and '500 Internal Server Error'

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ftp

Well I explain:

1 - I access via ftp by default (index.html, robots.txt and 'error' folder), I sobrescribo up WordPress files (before overwriting files on wordpress, and I access midominio.com 'I work 'I load the index.html by default).

2 - After finish loading all files in WordPress (thinking: how well I'll start the installation) came back to midominio.com and gives me error '500 Internal Server Error ', so here I remove the extension' vhost. '. This error has been removed, but now welcomes me to nginx 'Welcome to nginx!', And hence does not move (eg dominio.com / jajaijaa, it does not give 404 error or anything, continually 'Wlecome to nginx ! '). I can not install WordPress, the files on the ftp WordPress are just ... should not load the installation?

File (/ etc / nginx / sites-available / domain) I got so (upload it to pastebin to not to let the view):

http://pastebin.com/C8NGgMUA

Log file error: http://pastebin.com/8z7mrtae

Thanks

Comment: where's the wordpress vhost config?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).